# Web Analytics Connector and Conversion Tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud

i just want to ask about the conversion tracking with web analytics connector. Both features require adding the parameters to links. For example in web analytics connector we have to add email and in conversion tracking too. Could those features work together without any problems, assuming that it will be a lot of parameters in links, sometimes the same like email or mid?

Conversion Tracking http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/conversion_tracking/

Web Analytics Tracking 
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those features can work together which could result in duplicate data in the query string parameters. If you have control over your landing page consuming the query string parameters for conversion data then it would be possible to use the same parameter for both.